# User called mysql in fresh mariadb install on debian

Tags: mariadb, debian

I just installed MariaDB 10.4 on Debian 10.
In addition of root, there is a user called mysql.

Can I remove this user ?
What is the purpose of this account ?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not recommend to remove this account. DBMS daemon is started/executed using it. And it is difficult to reproduce the same permissions for another account. Whereas starting daemon using root-like account seems to be security risk.

Comment: Its purpose is there so it can do things like cleanly shutdown, logrotate, mysql_upgrade and all the other over engineered things Debian is so proud of.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, and as such it uses the latter name for many important things, including its command line tool `mysql, daemon binary`mysqld`, and the user ID`mysql` under whose authority the daemon runs. As mentioned in the comments, most Linux daemons run as their own dedicated user IDs for improved security.

Do not delete the user `mysql`.